# How to sort json table with sub array

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table

I have the following JSON (see below). I put the data in a html table and is working ok. I can sort on the name field, but how can I sort on the field punten in the points table in angularjs ?

I tried `orderBy values.points.punten` but that does not work.

```
    // create the list
$scope.values = [    
      {
          name: 'Johan',
          points: [
              {
                  punten: '4567',
                  pit: '1',
                  field: 'p0'
              },
              {
                  punten: '5422',
                  pit: '0',
                  field: 'p1'
              },              {
                  punten: '5422',
                  pit: '0',
                  field: 'p2'
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          name: 'Ton',
          points: [
              {
                  punten: '4444',
                  pit: '2',
                  field: 'p0'
              },
              {
                  punten: '5100',
                  pit: '1',
                  field: 'p1'
              },
              {
                  punten: '5423',
                  pit: '0',
                  field: 'p2'
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          name: 'Dian',
          points: [
              {
                  punten: '4765',
                  pit: '0',
                  field: 'p0'
              },
              {
                  punten: '4952',
                  pit: '0',
                  field: 'p1'
              },
              {
                  punten: '5424',
                  pit: '0',
                  field: 'p2'
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          name: 'Kees',
          points: [
              {
                  punten: '3765',
                  pit: '0',
                  field: 'p0'
              },
              {
                  punten: '3952',
                  pit: '0',
                  field: 'p1'
              },
              {
                  punten: '3424',
                  pit: '0',
                  field: 'p2'
              }
          ]
      }

  ];
```

Comment: Do you want to sort by field? Or filter by field?

Comment: I want to sort on the punten form high to low and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to `orderBy` **punten**

**Since you have `punten` in the points array,**

`<li ng-repeat="x in values | orderBy:'points[0].punten'">{{x}}</li>`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('orderCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.values = [    
      {
          name: "Johan",
          points: [
              {
                  punten: "4567",
                  pit: "1",
                  field: "p0"
              },
              {
                  punten: "5422",
                  pit: "0",
                  field: "p1"
              },              {
                  punten: "5422",
                  pit: "0",
                  field: "p2"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          name: "Ton",
          points: [
              {
                  punten: "4444",
                  pit: "2",
                  field: "p0"
              },
              {
                  punten: "5100",
                  pit: "1",
                  field: "p1"
              },
              {
                  punten: "5423",
                  pit: "0",
                  field: "p2"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          name: "Dian",
          points: [
              {
                  punten: "4765",
                  pit: "0",
                  field: "p0"
              },
              {
                  punten: "4952",
                  pit: "0",
                  field: "p1"
              },
              {
                  punten: "5424",
                  pit: "0",
                  field: "p2"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          name: "Kees",
          points: [
              {
                  punten: "3765",
                  pit: "0",
                  field: "p0"
              },
              {
                  punten: "3952",
                  pit: "0",
                  field: "p1"
              },
              {
                  punten: "3424",
                  pit: "0",
                  field: "p2"
              }
          ]
      }

  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="orderCtrl">

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in values | orderBy:'points[0].punten'">{{x}}</li><br>
</ul><br>

</div>



<p>The array items are displayed alphabetically.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**PLEASE RUN THE ABOVE SNIPPET**

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CMowfxLmrDnCfFm75cq9?p=preview)